# Generating WSDL from C++ (MFC Classes)

Tags: web-services, mfc, wsdl

I amd working on piece of requirement in which I need to design an interface/class in C++ which contains some methods or variable. And these methods I need to call for generating WSDL, which I will be using in some other middleware. I need to understand how C++ Code can be utilized for generating services or is there any third party available for generating WSDL for C++ code. Any kind of help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

This library
https://code.google.com/p/staff/
is for "Staff is a complete solution for building and deploying Web services in C++."

Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help , I have written a COM interface for this